# In Genesis 45:8, when Joseph said the plot to sell him by his brothers was God's plan, what did he mean?

Tags: genesis, joseph

Analyse why Joseph said the plot to sell him by his brothers was God's plan.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What do *you* think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in verses 5–7 (ESV):

> And now do not be distressed or angry with yourselves because you sold me here, for God sent me before you to preserve life. For the famine has been in the land these two years, and there are yet five years in which there will be neither plowing nor harvest. And God sent me before you to preserve for you a remnant on earth, and to keep alive for you many survivors.

By Genesis 45, Joseph can see the benefits of having been sold by his brothers: this way, he can save his family which is in desperate need of food. Joseph does not think this is a coincidence but that it was all part of a larger scheme of God.

Answer (score 0):

At seventeen God communicated to Joseph through dreams that upset his family (Genesis 37:1-11).  While Joseph at that time didn’t have the best people skills, he apparently had confidence that God would fulfill those dreams even through bad circumstances.

In Genesis 45:5-11 Joseph was able to look back and see that God had not only fulfilled the dreams God had given him, but God fulfilled a greater purpose than he originally realized, a ruler that saved the lives of the people he ruled.

Each bad thing that happened moved Joseph to the next step of where he needed to be.  When his brothers sold him, he went to Egypt.  When Potiphar’s wife accused him, he went to prison with Pharaoh’s servants, giving him the opportunity to interpret their dreams, resulting in Joseph having the opportunity to interpret Pharaoh’s dreams.

Joseph being put in a position of leadership multiple times (Genesis 39:4,22-23; 41:38-44) implies that Joseph had confidence in what God told him in his dreams and wasn’t bitter about his situation.  It is true that God blessed him, but bitterness would have ruined that blessing.